# Does editing a custom close reason comment change what shows up in the close dialog?

Tags: support, edits, custom-close-reasons

If you vote to close for a custom reason, Stack Overflow automatically posts a comment in your name with content copied from the close reason. The custom close reason will also show up in the close vote dialog as an option for future close-voters.

If you edit the generated comment, does this also change what shows up in the close vote dialog for other close-voters?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of purely scientific reasons. (This part is edited.) (This is also another edit purely for science made by a moderator)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XlyM.jpg

Comment: Also worth noting: people upvoted user2285236's comment manually, but anyone else trying to close while selecting the same reason would end up automatically doing so, like other such comments

Comment: @user2285236 Should have added, "Please do not vote to close this question." You've got 3 close votes now. lol.

Comment: @Patrice: but interestingly, if you *retract* a close vote on a custom reason which has caused the related comment to be auto-upvoted, it appears that the comment vote remains even when the close vote is retracted. I suppose I could manually removed the comment upvote but...why? :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis you can't retract a comment upvote after reloading the page.

Comment: @MEE - I learn somethin' new ever' day... :-)

Answer (score 27):

Science says yes:

[image: Close dialog with edited close reason from edited comment]

Comment: Looks like it... I made an edit to that comment (for science)  and it's reflected in the close dialog..

Comment: @JonClements Not only the close dialog. It edited the comment, too!

Comment: I like how user* is helping user* for... science!

Comment: I'm GLaD to see users do science for people who are still alive .

Comment: No mice were harmed during this experiment.

Comment: @Nisarg: MICE ARE THE ENEMY! (This message brought to you courtesy of the Feline Legal Defense Fund)